# linux common files between two folders

Tags: linux

Hello i have 2 directories both of them contains trees of directories 
and files. If it is possible, i need a script that verify common files 
between directories and if he find a common file i need to delete it in DIR2 and make link to DIR1.

`ex: 
    DIR1 includes dir abc1 , abc2, abc3 and abc1 contains file a.txt
    DIR2 includes dir abc1 , abc4, and abc4 contains file a.txt 
    Script should delete a.txt in DIR2/abc4 and make a link to DIR1/abc1/a.txt`

This script would be preferable to be in bash, awk, sed or perl.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an interview question.  Do you have a programming question in here somewhere?  Or are you just asking for someone to do your work for you?

Comment: Is not a interview question, i just dont know how to do it, and i need it in my script.

Comment: find -f will give you a list of files in a directory path.  xargs or something to hash the files.  then compare the hash + filepath lists.  then dedup ( unlink file, create symlink ).

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creating directories

```
mkdir -p DIR1/abc{1,2,3}
mkdir -p DIR2/abc{1,4}
```

Creating Files

```
touch DIR1/abc1/a.txt
touch DIR2/abc4/a.txt
```

Get all the files into temporary files

```
find DIR1 -name "*" -type f > DIR1.txt
find DIR2 -name "*" -type f > DIR2.txt
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
cat DIR1.txt|while read LINE
do
  FILE_NAME=`echo $LINE|awk -F"/" '{ print $NF }'`
  KEEP_FILE=$LINE

  cat DIR2.txt|while read LINE2
  do
    FILE_NAME2=`echo $LINE2|awk -F"/" '{ print $NF }'`
    if [ "${FILE_NAME}" == "${FILE_NAME2}" ]; then
      echo `rm $LINE2`
      ln -s `pwd`/$LINE $LINE2
    fi

  done
done
```